# How can I add Woocommerce best selling products to my home page?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a div on my home page that I want to contain the top 8 best selling products from my website. Seeing as I'm using Woocommerce I've looked around and found the short code, but I don't know how to add that to the div. Can anybody help solve this please? Thanks in advance!

Woocommerce shortcode:

```
add_shortcode('best_selling_products', 'woocommerce_best_selling_products');
```

HTML:

```
<div id="trending">
    add_shortcode('best_selling_products', 'woocommerce_best_selling_products');
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do_shortcode function is used to fire up shortcodes

```
<div id="trending">
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[best_selling_products]'); ?>
</div>
```

More: [do_shortcode()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this doesn't actually work. I just prints 'best_selling_products' in plane text in the div. Any alteration to this code?